# How to clear a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place a cross button next to a text field, which, on clicking it, clears the value entered by the user. In other words, it empties the field. Please help..
And I also want to focus the field, but after some 2 or 3 seconds..

Comment: Please just take an hour and read through the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It doesn't take any longer than that, and it gives you the answers to incredibly basic questions like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, a place where we welcome questions to any programming related problems that you may have, however, we ask that you first show a genuine attempt towards the solution in which you seek as we will not just give out free code to those who do not try it first themselves. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#myButton').click( function () {
    $('#myField').val('');
});
```

Or without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('myField').value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#inputBox').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything at all? But this should do (edit after misread, see below):

`$('#your_button').click(function() { $('#your_textbox').val(''); });`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('textField1').value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text field looks like this one :

```
<input type="text" id="myText"></input>
```

and your button looks like this one :

```
<input type="button" id="myButton"></input>
```

You just have to do this in javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
    myButton.addEventListener("click", function () { 
        document.getElementById('myText').value = ''; 
    }, false);
</script>
```

If you're using jQuery it's even easier :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myButton').click(function() {
      $('#myText').val('');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, learn to break your tasks into smaller one and everything will become much easier. Here, for example, you have 2 tasks:

1) Place a "X" button near input. This is achieved by CSS and HTML. You HTML might look like:

Then you should align your image with you input

2) Actual erasing. In jQuery:

```
$("#x_button").click( function() {
  $("#input_id").val( "" );    
});
```

But this is real basics of web development, so you should really consider to read some kind of book on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with html5 value.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your text here">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample:

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtText" value="test value" />
<input type="button" id="btnClear" value="Clear" />
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnClear").click(ClearText);
        });

        function ClearText() {
            $("#txtText").val("");
        }
```